# sending mail using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How send mail using ASP.NET MVC? Any example for this?

Comment: Are you taking about **emails** or actual **MAIL**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Gu's article is a bit dated, but still everything you need to know is there: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The same way as you would with any .NET application. [Send E-mail Message with C# or VB.NET](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sendemail)